# How can I export an XML File from an Excel Sheet and keep the Date Format?

Tags: excel, xml, navision, dynamics-business-central

For example, my date is 12.04.2008 (DD.MM.YYYY) but, when I export it, the XML File somehow converts it to this: 39550.

My XML template looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <DataImport>
        <No>001-MK</No>
        <CustNo>10016</CustNo>
        <PostingDate>05.12.2005</PostingDate>
    </DataImport>
</root>
```

Comment: No one has a solution?

Comment: 39550 is how Excel represents your date (you can check it by changing the cell format, or by using the `DATEVALUE` function)